# Using jQuery plugin for gradient, adding classes to create a hover effect causing jumping text

Tags: jquery, css, text, hover, gradient

I am working on a new site here: http://dsrp.tv/newdurak

I'm trying to add a gold gradient to text and remove it on hover. I couldn't figure out how to remove or change the gradient using the plugin so I tried to do it by adding CSS classes. I need a solution that works in Firefox so I can't use background-clip.

The problem with the current solution is that the hover state text jumps on the first mouseover event. I tried to trigger the mouseover event in advance on document load but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's the trigger I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //gold gradient for text
        $(".gold").pxgradient({
          step:4,
          colors: ["#efcd83", "#e9c279", "#d29856", "#cf9354"],
          dir: "y"
        });         

        $('.gold')
            .mouseenter(function() {
                $( this ).addClass('noshadow')
                         .addClass('pressed')
                         .addClass('hover');
            })
            .mouseleave(function() {
                $( this ).removeClass('noshadow')
                         .removeClass('pressed')
                         .removeClass('hover');
            });     

        //trigger hover on load
        $('li.gold').trigger('mouseenter'); 
        $('li.gold').trigger('mouseleave');

    });
```

Here's a link to the plugin: [jquery text gradient plugin](http://mrnix.ru/pxgradient/index_en.html)

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to remove the gradient from the text so I can hover a hover state using jQuery?
2. Is it possible to stop the text from jumping on the first mouseenter event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works. It needed the delay in between adding and removing the classes.

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('.gold').addClass('noshadow')
                  .addClass('pressed')
                  .addClass('hover');
        setTimeout(function (){                       
            $('.gold').removeClass('noshadow')
                     .removeClass('pressed')
                     .removeClass('hover');
            }, 500);    
    });
```